# What is a plausable way to implement my idea in an IOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am attempting to write an IOS app for a friend's startup company. I have some experience with objective-c but I am very much still a novice. My friend's website is similar in structure to Craigslist so in the app he wants people to be able to view posts on the website and create posts. My basic question is as follows: Would it be possible to have an SQLite database stored locally on the phone which would then update when users opened the app or switched views in the app? This may be a terrible idea Im just looking for feedback from someone more experienced.

Answer (score 1):

**YES** it is very common in iOS apps that requires offline access or a local database storage. You may look into [***Core data***](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) which provides api's to access SQLite database. Though you can keep a local copy of whatever data resides in the server. In a more advanced way you may want learn [***Rest kit***](http://restkit.org/) also